# Rules Concerning Electronics Onboard US-Bound Direct Flights

Tags: usa, airport-security, electronic-items, emirates

I am going to be traveling from Milan (MXP) to New York (JFK) in the summer. However, my flight is with Emirates, and Milan is actually a stopover with the plane originating from Dubai. Am I allowed to pack my electronics in my carry-on bags? I'm not sure if this rule applies to me since I'm not boarding from one of the affected countries. However, since this is a direct  flight originating from one of the countries in the electronics ban, does this rule apply regardless?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ban doesn't apply to you. From the [Emirates website](https://www.emirates.com/kw/english/help/faq/4090646/electronics-ban):

> This electronics ban **does not** apply to flights from Dubai International airport to the UK, flights into Australia, flights from Milan (EK205) and Athens (EK209) to the US, or to any other routes on the Emirates network.

Answer (score 3):

The American electronics ban *should* not apply to your journey.

From [here](https://www.travelweekly.com.au/article/details-of-airline-electronic-ban-arise/):

> The ban applies if…
>
> –      You’re flying to the US from Istanbul, Turkey; Dubai and Abu
>   Dhabi in the United Arab Emirates; Doha, Qatar; Amman, Jordan; Cairo,
>   Egypt; Casablanca, Morocco; Jeddah and Riyadh in Saudi Arabia; Kuwait
>   City, Kuwait
>
> –       You’re flying non-stop to the U.S. on one of these nine
>   airlines: EgyptAir; Emirates; Etihad Airways; Kuwait Airways; Qatar
>   Airways; Royal Air Maroc; Royal Jordanian; Saudia (Saudi Arabian
>   Airlines); Turkish Airlines.

But, that doesn't define how Emirates deals with this. To be sure, you should contact your airline.